# iWeb iFrames and smooth scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent, smooth-scrolling

I am using iWeb (horrible but i have to use it, long story).

I have managed to get some smooth scrolling links on a page but i am having trouble getting it to scroll to the correct location.

Here is my code for the "HTML Widget" which is loaded into an iframe (FYI this is the menu):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

// the var's are referneces to iWeb's generated div's have to publish and get id's
  var about     = "id1";
  var products  = "id4";
  var technical = "id7";
//  var contactus   = "id14";

$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body', window.parent.document).animate({
          //scrollTop: parent.document.getElementById(products).offsetTop // this works but is a static ref
          scrollTop: parent.document.getElementById(theTarget).offsetTop
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: "100%"; height: "0%"">
    <a href="#about" id="about" class="myButton">About</a>
    <a href="#products" id="products" class="myButton">Products</a>
    <a href="#technical" id="technical" class="myButton">Technical</a>
    <a href="#contactus" id="contactus" class="myButton">Contact</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when i view this an click on a link, it will just load the iframe page instead of scrolling the main window.

But if i comment/uncomment the other ScrollTop line it will work but obviously it will only scroll to the "id4" div in the parent window.

How can i get this to work the way i need it to without copy/pasting the same function over and over for each link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest sort of a dictionary to map the link hashes to element IDs:

```
var map = {
    '#about':     'id1',
    '#products':  'id4',
    '#technical': 'id7',
    '#contactus': 'id14',
};
```

This way you can then use `target` as a key to that map:

```
if (target.length && target in map) {
    $('html, body', window.parent.document).animate({
        scrollTop: parent.document.getElementById(map[target]).offsetTop,
    }, 1000);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats fantastic, it didn't quite work at first but here is the code i have used to get this fully working as intended:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = {
    'about':     'id1',
    'products':  'id4',
    'technical': 'id7',
    'contactus': 'id11',
};

$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);

      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body', window.parent.document).animate({
          scrollTop: parent.document.getElementById(map[this.hash.slice(1)]).offsetTop
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```